# detecting which accessory view is tapped in calloutAccessoryControlTapped delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I would like to detect if the rightCalloutAccessoryView has been tapped via the delegate method below, how can I do that?

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)contro
```

Comment: You have already implemented `calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` method? or, You want to know how to implement that? or, You have some other problem regarding this? Be more specific.

Comment: well there are two accessoryView, left and right.. so when is this delegate actually fired? Is it for both left and right accessoryView? I just want this one to be fired when the rightAccessoryView is tapped

Comment: calloutAccessoryControlTapped: method will be triggered for both left and right views. I have posted an answer here. Hope that will help you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`calloutAccessoryControlTapped` method will be triggered for the tap action on both `leftCalloutAccessoryView` and `rightCalloutAccessoryView`. To distinguish the accessory views, you can set `tag` for both the accessory views while you create them. And in your `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` method, you can check the tag value and do the respective action depending on the tag value.

For example, consider you have set `1` and `2` for the `tags` of your `left` and `right` accessory view respectively. Then your `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` method will look something like the following,

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {

    if ([control tag] == 1) {

        // Left Accessory Button Tapped

    } else if ([control tag] == 2) {

        // "Right Accessory Button Tapped
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine but I wonder if there is another method that do not use integer tag?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following implementation:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    switch control {
    case let left where left == view.leftCalloutAccessoryView:
        // tap on left
        break
    case let right where right == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView:
        // tap on right
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

The `switch` syntax is a bit more complicated than usual due to `leftCalloutAccessoryView` and `rightCalloutAccessoryView` being optionals, but it avoids using tags.